# How to stretch the last CSS flex item all the way to the right edge of the view port?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to clone the "editor's picks" of [this page](https://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2022/06/see-a-psychologist-for-back-pain-research-says-yes/)

This is the very selector I want to clone: `document.querySelector('.article-collection-teases__teases--layout-3-asymmetric .tz-article-collection--wide')`

It uses this `calc(((100vw - 1224px)/ 2) + 601px);` as it's width.

**I'm assuming the `601px` is not hard-coded**

I'm trying to replicate it [here](https://jsbin.com/sajexokeda/2/edit?css,output)

```css
.editors-picks{
  width: 900px;
  background:blue;
  margin: auto
}
.articles{
  display: flex;
}
.articles  div{
  min-width: 23.52941%;
  margin-right: 1.96078%;
  min-height: 40px;
  background:red; 
}

.articles .big{
  width: calc(((100vw - 900px)/ 2) + 401px);
  background: green;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="editors-picks">
<h3>Editor's Picks</h3>
<div class="articles">
  <div>d</div>
  <div>d</div>
  <div class="big">ddd</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure if I start adding a few more pixels to `401px` I can get the effect **but is there a logic behind the calculation?** Why does `601px` give them the effect it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative `margin-right` like below

```css
.editors-picks {
  max-width: 900px;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto
}

.articles {
  display: flex;
}

.articles div {
  min-width: 23.52941%;
  margin-right: 1.96078%;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.articles .big {
  /* if (screen width < 900px)
       margin-right= 0px
     else
       negative margin to cover the right side
  */
  margin-right: min(0px,(900px - 100vw)/ 2);
  background: green;
  flex-grow: 1; /* don't forget this */
}
```

```html
<div class="editors-picks">
  <h3>Editor's Picks</h3>
  <div class="articles">
    <div>d</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div class="big">ddd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Then,  if we have `<div class="big"><div class="one"></div> <div class="two"></div></div>` how would you  and only want `.one` to have that effect. (I got it working by adding `.articles .big .one {...}` but there's then a gap of `1.96078%`) https://jsbin.com/vojaqizodu/4/edit?html,output

Comment: @relidon you replace the 0px in the min() with a negative margin equal to that gap

Answer (score 0):

There is logic behind the calculation. And the calculation actual changes per breakpoints

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  width: calc(49.01961% + 25px + 1px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  width: calc(49.01961% + 60px + 1px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1070px) {
  width: calc(49.01961% + 80px + 1px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1384px) {
  width: calc(((100vw - 1224px)/ 2) + 601px);
}
```

To focus on the calculation in your question, for screen sizes larger than 1384px, we want to calculate the remaining space on the side of the screen to fill.

100vw - 1224px (the width of the centered container) = The remaining width of the browser viewport, then we divde that by 2 to get the width of just one side of the remanining space. And the 601px is the size of remaining space inside the container which is calculated by 1224px - 2 cards width and margins.

```
(287.992 + 23.992) * 2 = 623.968px (width of 2 cards)
1124px - 623.968px = ~600px (remaining width in container)
```

And then obviously the other breakpoints follow the same strategy.

For your code in the example, your container is 900px, and your 2 rigid columns are 211.76px wide with an additional 17.641px right margin. So the additional space you need to add for that breakpoint is

```
900 - ((211.76 + 17.641) * 2) = 441.198
```

Answer (score -2):

Just need to use `flex-grow: 1`

```css
.editors-picks {
  width: 900px;
  background: blue;
  margin: auto
}

.articles {
  display: flex;
}

.articles div {
  min-width: 23.52941%;
  margin-right: 1.96078%;
  min-height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.articles .big {
  background: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="editors-picks">
  <h3>Editor's Picks</h3>
  <div class="articles">
    <div>d</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div class="big">ddd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```